# stdout.readlines() returns UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, utf-8, paramiko, syslog

I'm connection to a machine using paramiko and extracting its syslog.
When I'm trying to use the function readlines(), I am getting UnicodeDecodeError.

This is the program:

```
print_all_lines="awk 'FNR>=%s && FNR <=%s' /var/log/syslog" %(line_number_start, line_number_end)
stdin, stdout, stderr = SSH.exec_command(print_all_lines)
stdout.readlines()
```

and this is the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 199: invalid continuation byte
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readline()` and `readlines()` would try to decode the data as `UTF-8` so it may fail if the data is not really in `UTF-8`. You can just use `read()` which would not do the decode:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = SSH.exec_command(print_all_lines)
s = stdout.read()
```

See following example (in the interactive python):

```
>>> stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(r'printf \\xc5\\n')
>>> v = stdout.readlines()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...snip...]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 0:
invalid continuation byte
>>>
>>> stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(r'printf \\xc5\\n')
>>> v = stdout.read()
>>> v
'\xc5\n'
>>>
```

---

#### UPDATE:

Just took a look at Paramiko's source code and it has an undocumented function `_set_mode()` which can be used to set *stdout* to *binary* mode which disables the decode:

```
>>> stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(r'printf \\xc5\\n\\xc5\\n')
>>> stdout._set_mode('b')
>>> v = stdout.readlines()
>>> v
['\xc5\n', '\xc5\n']
>>>
```